# What is the maximum radius of an Einstein ring?

Tags: black-hole, gravitational-lensing, radius

Is there an upper limit to how far out an Einstein ring can be visible? For black holes, is it a fixed multiple of their Schwarzschild radius?

Comment: What do you mean by "how far out"?

Comment: @ProfRob Based on the second sentence, one would guess it's angular distance seen by an observer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angular diameter (in radians) of an [Einstein ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_ring) is
$$\theta = \sqrt{\frac{4GM}{c^2}\;\frac{D_{LS}}{D_S D_L}}\ ,$$
where $M$ is the lens mass, $D_S$ and $D_L$ are the angular diameter distance to the source and lens respectively and $D_{LS}$ is the angular diameter distance between source and lens.

There isn't therefore any mathematical maximum, it depends on the geometry and lens mass.